# Harlan J. Brothers's approximation to $ e $ ad infinitum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation, exponential-function

Consider the series generated by Harlan J. Brothers's method for the number $e$

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_representations_of_e

Can they be improved again and again or is there a limit so there exists a BEST approximation to $e$?

Comment: [The paper](http://www.harlanjbrothers.com/docs/icnsae_(cmj0104-300dpi).pdf) is available on Harlan J. Brothers's [homepage](http://www.harlanjbrothers.com/).

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "improved" and  "BEST."  The paper @Martin referenced discusses "an algebraic assessment based on the decimal place accuracy (d.p.a.) that is gained from a given number of terms; the greater the d.p.a., the faster the series converges."  This is different from the run-time cost of the computation for which a smaller number of processor operations indicates that the algorithm is inherently more efficient.

While the combination of *T* terms results in new "compressed" terms containing a polynomial of degree *T*-1, the algorithm appears reasonably linear (to at least T=100).  Computing 30,000 terms with Newton's method achieves 121,287 correct digits.  Obtaining the same accuracy by computing 3,000 terms with *t*=10 requires very close to 1/10 the time - it's 9.9 times as fast (these computations are done in *Mathematica 9*).  Computing just 300 terms with *T*=100 is 96 times as fast.  However, for *T*=1000, things slow down - 30 terms are only 705 times as fast.  To my knowledge, there has been no evaluation of the true computational efficiency of the approach.

Personally, I find value in the aesthetic appeal of expressions resulting from combinations that use low values of *T*.  Here is a more comprehensive list of approximations that supplements the paper:

http://www.brotherstechnology.com/math/e-formulas.html

In short, Newton's series can indeed be algebraically improved again and again. The extent to which such "improvements" can continue to be of practical value is a different matter.  For proven efficiency, you can reference the work of the computational wizards cited here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_splitting

Comment: i mean he did only a formula for 'e' and became famous ? who judges who is famous and who is not in math ?

Comment: @JoseGarcia  Hi, Jose. I don’t know of anyone who would claim that I am “famous” in the field of mathematics or any other domain. However, a quick search will reveal that my body of work, which includes many peer-reviewed papers, encompasses far more than this accelerated series for e.

Comment: am D: you are famous you have your own wikipedia page :D and a job as a mathematician :) really envy you ..